# Prove that the adjoint of a densely defined operator is closed

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, self-adjoint-operators

I'd like to prove that the adjoint of a densely defined linear operator is closed.

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and $T: D(T)\rightarrow H$ a densely defined linear operator ($D(T)$ is a dense subspace of $H$). The domain of the adjoint is defined as $D(T^{\ast}):=\left\{x \in H: \exists y\in H \mbox{ with } \langle x,Tz \rangle=\langle y, z \rangle\; \forall z \in H\right\}$ and $T^{\ast}x=y$.

Let $\{x_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\subset D(T^{\ast})$ be a convergent sequence with $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_{n}=x$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}T^{\ast}x_{n}=y$. For $T^{\ast}$ to be closed I need to show:

1. $x \in D(T^{\ast})$
2. $T^{\ast}x=y$

1.)
$$
\begin{align}
\langle x, Tz \rangle
&=
\langle \lim_{n \to \infty}x_{n}, Tz \rangle\\
&=
\lim_{n \to \infty}\langle x_{n}, Tz \rangle\\
&=
\lim_{n \to \infty}\langle T^{\ast}x_{n}, z \rangle\\
&=
\langle\lim_{n \to \infty} T^{\ast}x_{n}, z \rangle\\
&=
\langle y, z \rangle\\
\end{align}
$$
and therefore $x \in D(T^{\ast})$.

2.)

Given 1.), the continuity of $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ and the definition of the adjoint we can show
$$
\begin{align}
\langle y, z \rangle
&=
\langle \lim_{n \to \infty}T^{\ast}x_{n}, z \rangle\\
&=
\lim_{n \to \infty} \langle T^{\ast}x_{n}, z \rangle\\
&=
\lim_{n \to \infty} \langle x_{n}, Tz \rangle\\
&=
\langle \lim_{n \to \infty}x_{n}, Tz \rangle\\
&=
\langle x, Tz \rangle\\
&=
\langle T^{\ast}x, z \rangle\\
\end{align}
$$
for all $z \in H$ and hence $y=T^{\ast}x$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: It is correct, but $1).$ suffices as the equality $\langle x,Tz\rangle =\langle y,z\rangle $ for any $z\in D(T)$ implies that $x\in D(T^*)$ and $T^*x=y.$